# With React Semantic UI use NavLink to set active page class?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

Im using Semantic UI React and React Router. The NavLink componenet from React Router knows then its the active page link and can set an active class:

```
<NavLink to="/" exact activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
```

However this doesn't work with Semantic UI React:

```
    <Menu.Item
      header
      as={NavLink}
      to="./"
      children="Diplomat"
      activeClassName="active"
    />
```

I can see in the browser that the aria-current property is being set to true correctly. So NavLink does 'know' when its active but I cant pass this to Menu.Item.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I made a mistake. I just needed an `exact` attribute and a different path. Now it works.

```
<Menu.Item header as={NavLink} exact to="/" children="Diplomat" />
```