# Why does my NavLink's doesn't set to active using Semantic-ui-react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, semantic-ui

I'm using combination of `Semantic-UI-React` and `react-router-dom`
I have a Navigation Component with just 2 links.

They look like this (`NavLink` comes from `react-router-dom`):

```
 <Menu.Item name="home" as={NavLink} to="/" />
 <Menu.Item name="protected" as={NavLink} exact to="/protected" />
```

When I click on the `Protected` Link on my site, the component loads and I'm on the /protected route. 
But the only link that is active is the `Home` NavLink.

I tried it with different variants. For example I added `activeClassName="active"` to both of them. 
I tried it with `exact` for all 2 or just one route. 
Nothing changes.

I found a related question: [With React Semantic UI use NavLink to set active page class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427342/with-react-semantic-ui-use-navlink-to-set-active-page-class)

I tried it exactly like this, but it won't work on my site.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

My Navbar component wasn't connected to the router. 
I connected it with the `withRouter` helper from `react-router-dom`

That fixed the problem. Code looks like this now:

```
<Menu.Item
  name="home"
  as={NavLink}
  exact
  to="/"
  activeClassName="active"
/>
<Menu.Item        
  name="protected"
  as={NavLink}
  to="/protected"
  activeClassName="active"
/>
```